# Solving triangle geometry problem involving bisections using homogeneous coordinates

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

This question is from the 2001 Putnam exam;

Triangle $$ has area $1$. Points $$, $$, $$ lie, respectively, on sides $$,
$$, $$ such that $$ bisects $$ at point $$, $$ bisects $$ at point $$, and
$$ bisects $$ at point $$. Find the area of the triangle $$.
[image: Problem figure]

I'm not sure if the entire solution is required for my question, so I will give what I think is necessary:

If we choose $$, $$, $$ so that $ = $, $ = $, $ = $, then, using applications of the sine formula we can arrive at the relation $(1 + ) = 1$. Similarly, $(1 + ) = (1 + ) = 1$. The solution I've seen then uses this fact to arrive at the area. But, the author leaves a remark at the end:

> Remark. The key relation $(1 + ) = 1$ can also be derived using
> homogeneous coordinates or vectors.

My question is: How can we actually derive this relation using homogeneous coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(0;0)$, $B(1;0)$, $C(0;1)$, then $E(r;1-r)$, $F(0;s)$. $R$ is middle of $BF$: $R(1/2;s/2)$. "Slope" of AE is the same as "slope" of AR: $\frac{1-r}{r}=\frac{s/2}{1/2}\Rightarrow 1-r=rs \Rightarrow r(1+s)=1$.